# Other ways to remove commas in a row of a given column

Tags: python, list

**Likes**

```
1.49
2.312
3.499
4.1,204
5.3,001
6.2,500
```

In the above `Likes` column there are six rows and I want to remove comma in rows  4, 5, and 6. I tried to remove the comma by using below mentioned code:

```
b=[]
c=train['Likes']
for i in c:
    d=i.split(',')
    e=d[0]+d[1]
    b.append(e)
train['likes']=b
```

After running the above code I got error as:

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-aaaf683b8888> in <module>
      3 for i in c:
      4     d=i.split(',')
----> 5     e=d[0]+d[1]
      6     b.append(e)
      7     #b.append(f)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to solve the above issue?

Comment: We are missing a lot of information here. What is "column"? a dataframe column? a csv "column"? anyway, the error you get hints that not all elements in the "column" contain a comma (perhaps an empty line at the end of the file you are reading)

Comment: if you're using `pandas` I think what you want is `train['likes'] = train.Likes.str.replace(',', '')`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is failing on the strings that don't contain a comma, meaning the list has just one element: the entire string.

```
>>> '1.49'.split(',')
['1.49']
```

To fix it, simply remove the comma with [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
i = i.replace(',', '')
```

For example:

```
>>> '1.49'.replace(',', '')
'1.49'
>>> '4.1,204'.replace(',', '')
'4.1204'
```